# How to retrieve the single document data and show it in app?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Here, I'm trying to print the username of the user and it produces the following error.
[image: The Error is as follows...]

I created a function userData() and the code is

```
userData() async
  {
    var userData = await _db.collection('users').document(_uuid).get();
    return userData;
  }
```

Where I'll just get the data of the specific user using uid and returning it.

The code I used to print the data is as follow

```
return FutureBuilder(
    future: authService.userData(),
    builder: (_,snapshots){
      if(snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
      {
        
        return Center(child: Text('Loading...'),);
      }
      else{
        print("Snapshots: "+snapshots.toString());
        return ListView.builder(itemCount: 1, itemBuilder: (_,index){
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(snapshots.data["username"].toString()),
          );
        });
      }
    }
  );
```

The structure of firestore is

Collection('user') -> document(uid) -> 1.username 2.email ....

What is the reason for this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `snapshots.data` is null, so you can't index into it with the `[]` operator.

Before using a [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html), you should check to see if it [exists](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/exists.html) before accessing its field data.  The snapshot's [data](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) property will be null if the document doesn't exist.

Comment: For testing purpose, I used a document ID that is present in firestore. Since it returns null . what is the reason?

Comment: The SDK is telling you that the document doesn't exist.  I can't verify that, because I can't see the data you're working with.

Comment: Yeah now I have updated the firestore data as image

Comment: We still can't see that you're passing the correct value of `_uuid`.  If you pass anything other than the ID of the document, your snapshot will contain no data.

Comment: I just assigned _uuid as the same in firestore. By just copying and pasted and assigned the value for _uuid

Comment: Since we can't see that, there's nothing we can do to help.  The results from the SDK are clear.

Answer (score 0):

For Firestore I would recommend using Stream Builder rather than future Builder.

```
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection('user')
                .document(uid)
                .snapshots(),
    builder: (_,snapshot){
      if(!snapshot.hasData)
      {
        
        return Center(child: Text('Loading...'),);
      }
      else{
        
        return ListView.builder(itemCount: 1, itemBuilder: (_,index){
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(snapshots.data["username"].toString()),
          );
        });
      }
    }
  );
```